# How to navigate through SwiftUI TextFields by clicking on return button from keyboard?

Tags: ios, textfield, swiftui

I'm working with SwiftUI's `TextField View`. Mainly I have 2 questions:

1. In Swift, we can set **Return Key(Text Input Traits)** to `Next` for TextField from storyboard like this right? For this which modifier to use in SwiftUI?
   [image]
2. I have two Textfields, how to navigate to the next TextField when I click return/next button from keyboard?

Can anyone help with this using SwiftUI (not UIKit)? Or any other alternative to perform this feature?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To resolve your two problems, you need to work with **UIKit** from **SwiftUI**. First, you need to customized **TextField** using **UIViewRepresentable**. Here is the sample code for test purposes though the code is not so elegance. I bet, there will be having a more robust solution.

1. Inside the customized TextFieldType, the Keyboard return type has
   been set.
2. By using object binding and delegate methods
   **textFieldShouldReturn**, View can focus the keyboard by updating the binding variables.

Here is the sample code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct KeyboardTypeView: View {
    @State var firstName = ""
    @State var lastName = ""
    @State var focused: [Bool] = [true, false]

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Your Info")) {
                TextFieldTyped(keyboardType: .default, returnVal: .next, tag: 0, text: self.$firstName, isfocusAble: self.$focused)
                TextFieldTyped(keyboardType: .default, returnVal: .done, tag: 1, text: self.$lastName, isfocusAble: self.$focused)
                Text("Full Name :" + self.firstName + " " + self.lastName)
            }
        }
}
}



struct TextFieldTyped: UIViewRepresentable {
    let keyboardType: UIKeyboardType
    let returnVal: UIReturnKeyType
    let tag: Int
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var isfocusAble: [Bool]

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.keyboardType = self.keyboardType
        textField.returnKeyType = self.returnVal
        textField.tag = self.tag
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no

        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        if isfocusAble[tag] {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            uiView.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: TextFieldTyped

        init(_ textField: TextFieldTyped) {
            self.parent = textField
        }

        func updatefocus(textfield: UITextField) {
            textfield.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

            if parent.tag == 0 {
                parent.isfocusAble = [false, true]
                parent.text = textField.text ?? ""
            } else if parent.tag == 1 {
                parent.isfocusAble = [false, false]
                parent.text = textField.text ?? ""
         }
        return true
        }

    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Good solution. Thank you. That's such a common use case, especially within forms. Isn't there a Swifter solution for resolving that?

Comment: This seems to only work for the `.default` type. Or at least it's not working for both `numberPad` and `decimalPad`. Any ideas on how to make these work if at all possible?

Comment: This can be achieved with purely SwiftUI now using FocusState and closures - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70293614/5632572  OP said they only have 2 text fields, so this solution from Razib with an Enum is better in this case

Answer (score 6):

## iOS 15.0+

macOS 12.0+,
Mac Catalyst 15.0+,
tvOS 15.0+,
watchOS 8.0+

> Use `submitLabel(_:)` view modifier that sets the submit label for a view. It takes a predefined case specified in `SubmitLabel`

> Use `.next`. It defines a submit label with text of **“Next”**.

> Use `onFocus(_:)` to find when the modified view hierarchy, in this case the `TextField`, loses focus. When it does, put the focus on the next view (`SecureField`)

```
struct LoginForm: View {
    enum Field: Hashable {
        case usernameField
        case passwordField
    }
    
    @State private var username = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Username", text: $username)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .usernameField)
                .submitLabel(.next)
                .onFocus { isFocused in
                    if (!isFocused) {
                        focusedField = .passwordField
                    }
                }
            
            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .passwordField)
                .submitLabel(.done)
        }
    }
}
```

- [submitLabel(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/submitlabel(_:))
- [SubmitLabel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/submitlabel)
- [.next](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/submitlabel/next)
- [onfocus(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/focused(_:))

Comment: Does it supposed to go to the next textfield when the next button was clicked? If so, it doesn't work for me :/

Comment: .onFocus has been deprecated. It won't be released.

Comment: I read it in Apple’s latest beta documentation. .focused is still good. @FocusState is still good. Instead of .onFocus, you need to use .onChange with FocusState.

Comment: Yeh `onFocus` has been removed. Any idea what to use instead?

Comment: Ok, we can use `.onSubmit()`

Comment: onFocus has not been removed. I just tested this. Read the update part. @adamek

Comment: I was able to achieve this without an Enum as well - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70293614/5632572

Comment: Here's a link to a blog post that shares how to do it in SwiftUI 3 (for iOS15+): https://swiftuirecipes.com/blog/navigate-fields-using-keyboard-in-swiftui

Answer (score 1):

You can't, there is no concept of a responder chain in SwiftUI yet. You can't programmatically initiate focus on any `View` because they aren't actually the views themselves, merely structs that describe how the views should be set up. My guess it may eventually be exposed via `EnvironmentValues` (like line truncation, autocorrection, etc.) but it doesn't currently exist.

Comment: has this changed, is there any way to resolve this now!?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Razib Mollick's answer and
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/100-days-of-swiftui/jump-focus-between-a-series-of-textfields-pin-code-style-entry-widget/765

I've come up with the following implementation for array of textfields.

```
struct NextLineTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
@Binding var text: String
@Binding var selectedField: Int

var tag: Int
var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType = .asciiCapable
var returnKey: UIReturnKeyType = .next

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<NextLineTextField>) -> UITextField {
    let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
    textField.delegate = context.coordinator
    textField.keyboardType = keyboardType
    textField.returnKeyType = returnKey
    textField.tag = tag
    return textField
}

func makeCoordinator() -> NextLineTextField.Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(text: $text)
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<NextLineTextField>) {
    uiView.text = text
    context.coordinator.newSelection = { newSelection in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.selectedField = newSelection
        }
    }

    if uiView.tag == self.selectedField {
        uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @Binding var text: String
    var newSelection: (Int) -> () = { _ in }

    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        _text = text
    }

    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.text = textField.text ?? ""
        }
    }
    
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.newSelection(textField.tag)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField.returnKeyType == .done {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        } else {
            self.newSelection(textField.tag + 1)
        }
        return true
    }
  }
}
```

Then make form element as

```
class FieldElement: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
var id = UUID()
var title = ""
@Published var value = ""
var keyboard: UIKeyboardType = .asciiCapable
var returnType: UIReturnKeyType = .next

init(title: String, value: String = "", keyboard: UIKeyboardType = 
    .asciiCapable, returnType: UIReturnKeyType = .next) {
    self.title = title
    self.value = value
    self.keyboard = keyboard
    self.returnType = returnType
  }
}
```

And for implementation

```
struct FormView: View {

@State var formElements: [FieldElement] = [
    FieldElement(title: "Name"),
    FieldElement(title: "Address"),
    FieldElement(title: "Phone Number"),
    FieldElement(title: "Email Address", keyboard: .emailAddress, returnType: 
.done),
]

@State var selectedField = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        ForEach(Array(zip(formElements.indices, formElements)), id: \.0) { 
        index, element in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text(element.title)

                NextLineTextField(text: self.$formElements[index].value,
                    selectedField: self.$selectedField,
                    tag: index,
                    keyboardType: element.keyboard,
                    returnKey: element.returnType)
                    .frame(height: 35)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.5), lineWidth: 0.7)
                    )
            }.padding(.bottom, 4)
        }

        Button(action: {
            print(self.formElements.map({ $0.value }))
        }) {
            Text("Print Entered Values")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .font(.body)
                .padding()
        }.frame(height: 50)
            .background(Color.green)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
        Spacer()
    }.padding()
  }
}
```

If this is hard to navigate, feel free to look into
https://github.com/prakshapan/Utilities/blob/master/FormView.swift

Answer (score 1):

From **iOS 15+**, we can handle keyboard action using `@FocusState` and `onSubmit()`,

```html
struct TextFieldFocus: View {
    enum Field {
        case userName, password
    }
    @State var field1 = ""
    @State var field2 = ""
    @FocusState var focusedField: Field?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20.0) {
            TextField("User name", text: $field1)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .userName)
                .submitLabel(.next)
                .padding()
                .onSubmit {
                    focusedField = .password
                }
            
            SecureField("Password", text: $field2)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .password)
                .submitLabel(.continue)
                .padding()
                .onSubmit {
                    focusedField = .userName
                }
        }
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
    }
}
```

Comment: good answer, but remove the padding() since it isn't necessary

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small library that enables automatic navigation between TextFields upon submission: [FormView](https://github.com/maxial/FormView). It also has useful features such as:

- Validation of TextFields based on specified rules
- Prevention of incorrect input based on specified rules