# Change focus on textfield after typing in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

I want to create a code validation textfield in my SwiftUI app, I already done it in UIKit this way.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if !(string.isEmpty) {
        textField.text = string
        if textField == textField1 { textField2.becomeFirstResponder() }
        else if textField == textField2 { textField3.becomeFirstResponder() }
        else if textField == textField3 { textField4.becomeFirstResponder() }
        else if textField == textField4 { textfield5.becomeFirstResponder() }
        else { textField.resignFirstResponder() }
        return false
    } else {
        textField.text = string
        if textField == textfield5 { textField4.becomeFirstResponder() }
        else if textField == textField4 { textField3.becomeFirstResponder() }
        else if textField == textField3 { textField2.becomeFirstResponder() }
        else if textField == textField2 { textField1.becomeFirstResponder() }
        else { textField.resignFirstResponder() }
        return false
    }
}
```

now I saw some answers about this question like:

[Focus on the next TextField/SecureField in Swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422440/focus-on-the-next-textfield-securefield-in-swiftui)

but it did not help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no delegate for this in SwiftUI