# How to move to next TextField in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, textfield, swiftui, first-responder

Using Swift5.1.2, iOS13.2, Xcode-11.2,

Having several TextFields in a Stackview, I would like to move to the next TextField as soon as the user types x-amount of characters into the first TextField.

With [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58673066/3826232), I achieve to recognise when a TextField entry has reached x-amount of characters. However, I do not know how to make the firstResponder jump to a second TextField inside my StackView.

Is there a solution to this with SwiftUI ?

Comment: I don't have a complete answer written in SwiftUI, but I would first get the index of the current firstResponder in the StackView using `stackView.arrangedSubviews.firstIndex(of: view)`. Then, get the arrangedSubview of the `found index + 1`, and make that firstResponder using `becomeFirstResponder()`.

Comment: In iOS 15 we can now use `@FocusState` to control which field should be focused - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68010971/8697793).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## iOS 15+

Use @FocusState

## Before iOS 15

I've taken @Philip Borbon answer and cleaned it up a little bit. I've removed a lot of the customization and kept in the bare minimum to make it easier to see what's required.

```
struct CustomTextfield: UIViewRepresentable {
    let label: String
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var focusable: Binding<[Bool]>? = nil
    
    var returnKeyType: UIReturnKeyType = .default
    
    var tag: Int? = nil
    
    var onCommit: (() -> Void)? = nil
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.placeholder = label
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        textField.returnKeyType = returnKeyType
        
        if let tag = tag {
            textField.tag = tag
        }
        
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        
        if let focusable = focusable?.wrappedValue {
            var resignResponder = true
            
            for (index, focused) in focusable.enumerated() {
                if uiView.tag == index && focused {
                    uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
                    resignResponder = false
                    break
                }
            }
            
            if resignResponder {
                uiView.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        let parent: CustomTextfield
        
        init(_ parent: CustomTextfield) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            guard var focusable = parent.focusable?.wrappedValue else { return }
            
            for i in 0...(focusable.count - 1) {
                focusable[i] = (textField.tag == i)
            }
            parent.focusable?.wrappedValue = focusable
        }
        
        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            guard var focusable = parent.focusable?.wrappedValue else {
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
                return true
            }
            
            for i in 0...(focusable.count - 1) {
                focusable[i] = (textField.tag + 1 == i)
            }
            
            parent.focusable?.wrappedValue = focusable
            
            if textField.tag == focusable.count - 1 {
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
            }
            
            return true
        }
        
        @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
            parent.text = textField.text ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to achieve this without UIViewRepresentable in iOS 15 https://stackoverflow.com/a/70293614/5632572

Comment: Updated the answer to include iOS 15 solution.

Comment: Looks like you removed a little bit too much. `        textField.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)` is still needed (it's not part of `UITextFieldDelegate`).

Comment: This works very well but when the next textfield is hidden by the keyboard I got the "AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute" error and the next textfield is not focused. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Fixed my AttributeGraph error with this answer: Fixed with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70238866/1639825

Answer (score 12):

## Using iOS 15+ @FocusState - Generic solution

Example usage:

```swift
@FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
enum Field: Int, Hashable {
   case name
   case country
   case city
}

var body: some View {
    TextField(text: $name)
        .focused($focusedField, equals: .name)
        .onSubmit { self.focusNextField($focusedField) }
// ...
```

Code:

````swift
extension View {
    /// Focuses next field in sequence, from the given `FocusState`.
    /// Requires a currently active focus state and a next field available in the sequence.
    ///
    /// Example usage:
    /// ```
    /// .onSubmit { self.focusNextField($focusedField) }
    /// ```
    /// Given that `focusField` is an enum that represents the focusable fields. For example:
    /// ```
    /// @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
    /// enum Field: Int, Hashable {
    ///    case name
    ///    case country
    ///    case city
    /// }
    /// ```
    func focusNextField<F: RawRepresentable>(_ field: FocusState<F?>.Binding) where F.RawValue == Int {
        guard let currentValue = field.wrappedValue else { return }
        let nextValue = currentValue.rawValue + 1
        if let newValue = F.init(rawValue: nextValue) {
            field.wrappedValue = newValue
        }
    }

    /// Focuses previous field in sequence, from the given `FocusState`.
    /// Requires a currently active focus state and a previous field available in the sequence.
    ///
    /// Example usage:
    /// ```
    /// .onSubmit { self.focusNextField($focusedField) }
    /// ```
    /// Given that `focusField` is an enum that represents the focusable fields. For example:
    /// ```
    /// @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
    /// enum Field: Int, Hashable {
    ///    case name
    ///    case country
    ///    case city
    /// }
    /// ```
    func focusPreviousField<F: RawRepresentable>(_ field: FocusState<F?>.Binding) where F.RawValue == Int {
        guard let currentValue = field.wrappedValue else { return }
        let nextValue = currentValue.rawValue - 1
        if let newValue = F.init(rawValue: nextValue) {
            field.wrappedValue = newValue
        }
    }
}
````

Answer (score 9):

I'm using `UITextField` and `UIViewRepresentable` to achieve this.

Define `tag` of each text field and declare a list of booleans with same count of available text fields to be focused of return key, `fieldFocus`, that will keep track of which textfield to focus next base on the current index/tag.

Usage:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Sample: View {
    @State var firstName: String = ""
    @State var lastName: String = ""
    
    @State var fieldFocus = [false, false]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            KitTextField (
                label: "First name",
                text: $firstName,
                focusable: $fieldFocus,
                returnKeyType: .next,
                tag: 0
            )
            .padding()
            .frame(height: 48)
            
            KitTextField (
                label: "Last name",
                text: $lastName,
                focusable: $fieldFocus,
                returnKeyType: .done,
                tag: 1
            )
            .padding()
            .frame(height: 48)
        }
    }
}
```

`UITextField` in `UIViewRepresentable`:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct KitTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    let label: String
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var focusable: Binding<[Bool]>? = nil
    var isSecureTextEntry: Binding<Bool>? = nil
    
    var returnKeyType: UIReturnKeyType = .default
    var autocapitalizationType: UITextAutocapitalizationType = .none
    var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType = .default
    var textContentType: UITextContentType? = nil
    
    var tag: Int? = nil
    var inputAccessoryView: UIToolbar? = nil
    
    var onCommit: (() -> Void)? = nil
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.placeholder = label
        
        textField.returnKeyType = returnKeyType
        textField.autocapitalizationType = autocapitalizationType
        textField.keyboardType = keyboardType
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = isSecureTextEntry?.wrappedValue ?? false
        textField.textContentType = textContentType
        textField.textAlignment = .left
        
        if let tag = tag {
            textField.tag = tag
        }
        
        textField.inputAccessoryView = inputAccessoryView
        textField.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        
        textField.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        uiView.isSecureTextEntry = isSecureTextEntry?.wrappedValue ?? false
        
        if let focusable = focusable?.wrappedValue {
            var resignResponder = true
            
            for (index, focused) in focusable.enumerated() {
                if uiView.tag == index && focused {
                    uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
                    resignResponder = false
                    break
                }
            }
            
            if resignResponder {
                uiView.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        let control: KitTextField
        
        init(_ control: KitTextField) {
            self.control = control
        }
        
        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            guard var focusable = control.focusable?.wrappedValue else { return }
            
            for i in 0...(focusable.count - 1) {
                focusable[i] = (textField.tag == i)
            }
            
            control.focusable?.wrappedValue = focusable
        }
        
        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            guard var focusable = control.focusable?.wrappedValue else {
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
                return true
            }
            
            for i in 0...(focusable.count - 1) {
                focusable[i] = (textField.tag + 1 == i)
            }
            
            control.focusable?.wrappedValue = focusable
            
            if textField.tag == focusable.count - 1 {
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
            }
            
            return true
        }
        
        func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            control.onCommit?()
        }
        
        @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
            control.text = textField.text ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: this is really cool, can you make a simpler version of it? I'm attempting to implement your solution but I'm not really sure of the bindings that are required. Even adding some documentation would be nice.

Comment: The required parameters to make it move to next fields are `label`, `text`, `focusable`, and `tag`. I just have the other parameters to expose some the `UITextField` properties to customize it or base on my usage, you can omit or expose properties you need or don't need.

Comment: @xTwisteDx I've posted an answer where I made this solution a little simpler.

Answer (score 6):

## iOS 15

This year, apple introduced a new modifier alongside with a new wrapper called `@FocusState` that controls the state of the keyboard and the focused keyboard ('aka' firstResponder).

Here is the example of how you can iterate over textFields:

[image: Demo]

Also, you can take a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59059359/5623035)** to see how you can make a textField first responder or resign it to hide the keyboard and learn more about how to bind this enum to the textFields.

Comment: how do you get those up and down arrows automatically?

Comment: Simple `.toolbar` items

Answer (score 6):

### iOS 15+

In iOS 15 we can now use [`@FocusState`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/focusstate/) to control which field should be focused.

Here is a demo:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var street: String = ""
    @State private var city: String = ""
    @State private var country: String = ""

    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Street", text: $street)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .street)
                TextField("City", text: $city)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .city)
                TextField("Country", text: $country)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .country)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Button(action: focusPreviousField) {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.up")
                    }
                    .disabled(!canFocusPreviousField()) // remove this to loop through fields
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Button(action: focusNextField) {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                    }
                    .disabled(!canFocusNextField()) // remove this to loop through fields
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
extension ContentView {
    private enum Field: Int, CaseIterable {
        case street, city, country
    }
    
    private func focusPreviousField() {
        focusedField = focusedField.map {
            Field(rawValue: $0.rawValue - 1) ?? .country
        }
    }

    private func focusNextField() {
        focusedField = focusedField.map {
            Field(rawValue: $0.rawValue + 1) ?? .street
        }
    }
    
    private func canFocusPreviousField() -> Bool {
        guard let currentFocusedField = focusedField else {
            return false
        }
        return currentFocusedField.rawValue > 0
    }

    private func canFocusNextField() -> Bool {
        guard let currentFocusedField = focusedField else {
            return false
        }
        return currentFocusedField.rawValue < Field.allCases.count - 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ResponderTextField: UIViewRepresentable {

    typealias TheUIView = UITextField
    var isFirstResponder: Bool
    var configuration = { (view: TheUIView) in }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> TheUIView { TheUIView() }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: TheUIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) {
        _ = isFirstResponder ? uiView.becomeFirstResponder() : uiView.resignFirstResponder()
        configuration(uiView)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var entry = ""
    @State private var entry2 = ""

    let characterLimit = 6

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("hallo", text: $entry)
                .disabled(entry.count > (characterLimit - 1))

            ResponderTextField(isFirstResponder: entry.count > (characterLimit - 1)) { uiView in
                uiView.placeholder = "2nd textField"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: at least it has a vote up ;) and yes, it worked when i wrote it

Comment: @Learn2Code, it works. Just plug his / her code into a view and see by yourself. However it will move from first to second textfield but don't see how to move the 3rd, 4th ...

Comment: never mind the 3rd, 4th ... It's easily modifiable to make it work :)

Comment: @GrandSteph How did you modify it to accommodate 3rd and 4th text fields? I need to have 6...

Comment: @Jack I ended up not using this code. Instead I used something similar to [this](https://github.com/valvoline/SATextField) SATexfield as I found that it was easier and more versatile and cleaner

Answer (score 2):

Solution proposed by Mojtaba is great if you can work with iOS 15. Since most projects have to support old versions of iOS it doesn't work. However, if you're using iOS 13 or iOS 14 you can use Focuser library which offers exactly that.[image]

You can download example project from Github to see an example. However API is modelled to work as in iOS 15.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer from Michael Ellis, you can eliminate the isFocused @FocusState in favor of changing the @State focus var to be a @FocusState:

```
    @FocusState var focus: MyObject?

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack {
                Text("Header")
                ForEach(self.myObjects) { obj in
                    Divider()
                    FocusField(displayObject: obj, focus: $focus, nextFocus: {
                        guard let index = self.myObjects.firstIndex(of: $0) else {
                            return
                        }
                        self.focus = myObjects.indices.contains(index + 1) ? myObjects[index + 1] : nil
                    })
                }
                Divider()
                Text("Footer")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FocusField: View {
    @State var displayObject: MyObject
    @Binding var focus: FocusState<MyObject?>.Binding
    var nextFocus: (MyObject) -> Void

    var body: some View {
    TextField("Test", text: $displayObject.value)
            .focused(self.focus, equals: displayObject)
            .submitLabel(.next)
            .onSubmit {
                self.nextFocus(displayObject)
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe finally in iOS 15 there is a real SwiftUI solution to this issue.

I [had this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70268416/how-can-one-change-the-focusstate-of-a-swiftui-app-with-textfields-in-different), and [wrote and article about it](https://medium.com/@michaelrobertellis/how-to-programmatically-manage-focusstate-for-dynamically-created-textfields-and-texteditors-in-5516de893d1a) since I couldn't find one.

Basically you can create a few things to accomplish this:

- Focus Object: An observed Identifiable object or array index int variable for your focus
- Focusable Objects Array: An array of Identifiable objects associated with the TextFields you want to iterate over as First Responders
- TextFieldWrapper: An object to manage each TextField's FocusState and to update the Focus Object(see first bullet)

Then you pass a closure or func reference to a TextField Wrapper object to allow it to update the Focused Object from your array. I would use a View Model of some kind, a FocusStateViewModel maybe. You can make a more complex solution to fit your needs [from this gist](https://gist.github.com/michael94ellis/4e877ae9ddecf19b55bbc8b8248ac69f)

[image]

Or, here is a minimal reproduction of the solution:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyObject: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id: String
    public var value: String
    init(name: String, value: String) {
        self.id = name
        self.value = value
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var myObjects: [MyObject] = [
        MyObject(name: "aa", value: "1"),
        MyObject(name: "bb", value: "2"),
        MyObject(name: "cc", value: "3"),
        MyObject(name: "dd", value: "4")
    ]
    @State var focus: MyObject?

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack {
                Text("Header")
                ForEach(self.myObjects) { obj in
                    Divider()
                    FocusField(displayObject: obj, focus: $focus, nextFocus: {
                        guard let index = self.myObjects.firstIndex(of: $0) else {
                            return
                        }
                        self.focus = myObjects.indices.contains(index + 1) ? myObjects[index + 1] : nil
                    })
                }
                Divider()
                Text("Footer")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FocusField: View {

    @State var displayObject: MyObject
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool
    @Binding var focus: MyObject?
    var nextFocus: (MyObject) -> Void

    var body: some View {
    TextField("Test", text: $displayObject.value)
            .onChange(of: focus, perform: { newValue in
                self.isFocused = newValue == displayObject
            })
            .focused(self.$isFocused)
            .submitLabel(.next)
            .onSubmit {
                self.nextFocus(displayObject)
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this done with Introspect library. https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect:

```
              @State private var passcode = ""

              HStack {
                  TextField("", text: self.$passcode)
                    .introspectTextField { textField in
                      if self.passcode.count >= 1 {
                        textField.resignFirstResponder()
                      } else if self.passcode.count < 1 {
                        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
                      }
                  }
                  TextField("", text: self.$passcode)
                    .introspectTextField { textField in
                      if self.passcode.count >= 2
                        textField.resignFirstResponder()
                      } else if self.passcode.count < 2 {
                        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
                      }
                  }
              }
```

I may have messed up the implementation from trying to copy and paste my code but you get the gist of how it would work.

Comment: That will not work as expected, because it'll jump on to the next field during the user is typing. That's confusing.