# Animating the change of colors when text field is changed using Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, colors

I created an OTP page that changes the color of underlines if the text field with the corresponding line is selected. The color changes properly but I want to add animation that the color of the line will change slowly like there's an animation. I have attached an example of what is expected and the current behavior.

I tried to add ease in animation but there's a problem when dismissing the number and text. They both don't go down or transition at the same time. In the recording the lines went down a little behind when I tapped done.

PS. I can only use Xcode 12.3 version.

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class OTPViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var otpField = "" {
        didSet {
            isNextTypedArr = Array(repeating: false, count: 6)
            guard otpField.count <= 6,
                  otpField.last?.isNumber ?? true else {
                otpField = oldValue
                return
            }
            if otpField.count < 6 {
                isNextTypedArr[otpField.count] = true
            }
        }
    }
    var otp1: String {
        guard otpField.count >= 1 else {
            return ""
        }
        return String(Array(otpField)[0])
    }
    var otp2: String {
        guard otpField.count >= 2 else {
            return ""
        }
        return String(Array(otpField)[1])
    }
    var otp3: String {
        guard otpField.count >= 3 else {
            return ""
        }
        return String(Array(otpField)[2])
    }
    var otp4: String {
        guard otpField.count >= 4 else {
            return ""
        }
        return String(Array(otpField)[3])
    }
    
    var otp5: String {
        guard otpField.count >= 5 else {
            return ""
        }
        return String(Array(otpField)[4])
    }
    
    var otp6: String {
        guard otpField.count >= 6 else {
            return ""
        }
        return String(Array(otpField)[5])
    }
    
    @Published var isNextTypedArr = Array(repeating: false, count: 6)
    
    @Published var borderColor: Color = .black
    
    @Published var isEditing = false {
        didSet {
            isNextTypedArr = Array(repeating: false, count: 6)
            if isEditing && otpField.count < 6 {
                isNextTypedArr[otpField.count] = true
            }
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct CXLRPOTPView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = OTPViewModel()
    
    let textBoxWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 8
    let textBoxHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 8
    let spaceBetweenLines: CGFloat = 16
    let paddingOfBox: CGFloat = 1
    var textFieldOriginalWidth: CGFloat {
        (textBoxWidth*6)+(spaceBetweenLines*3)+((paddingOfBox*2)*3)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                HStack (spacing: spaceBetweenLines){
                    otpText(text: viewModel.otp1, isNextTyped: $viewModel.isNextTypedArr[0])
                    otpText(text: viewModel.otp2, isNextTyped: $viewModel.isNextTypedArr[1])
                    otpText(text: viewModel.otp3, isNextTyped: $viewModel.isNextTypedArr[2])
                    otpText(text: viewModel.otp4, isNextTyped: $viewModel.isNextTypedArr[3])
                    otpText(text: viewModel.otp5, isNextTyped: $viewModel.isNextTypedArr[4])
                    otpText(text: viewModel.otp6, isNextTyped: $viewModel.isNextTypedArr[5])
                }
                
                TextField("", text: $viewModel.otpField) { isEditing in
                    viewModel.isEditing = isEditing
                }
                .frame(width: viewModel.isEditing ? 0 : textFieldOriginalWidth, height: textBoxHeight)
                .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
                .foregroundColor(.clear)
                .accentColor(.clear)
                .background(Color.clear)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            }
        }
    }
    
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    private func otpText(text: String, isNextTyped: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        return Text(text)
            .font(Font.custom("GTWalsheim-Regular", size: 34))
            .frame(width: textBoxWidth, height: textBoxHeight)
            .background(VStack{
                Spacer()
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 1)
                    .frame(height: 2)
                    .foregroundColor(isNextTyped.wrappedValue ? Color(hex: "#367878") : Color(hex: "#BCBEC0"))
                    .animation(.easeIn) //this made the text bounced.
            })
            .padding(paddingOfBox)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't actually offsetting the color, so it just does a color fade by default. I made the green underline a separate part, that offsets depending on where the cursor currently is.

To solve the animation problem where it animates even when doing something unrelated - use `.animation(_:value:)` instead - providing a value where the animation **only** happens when that value changes.

Change the `otpText` method to:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
private func otpText(text: String, isEditing: Bool, beforeCursor: Bool, afterCursor: Bool) -> some View {
    return Text(text)
        .font(Font.custom("GTWalsheim-Regular", size: 34))
        .frame(width: textBoxWidth, height: textBoxHeight)
        .background(VStack{
            Spacer()

            ZStack {
                Capsule()
                    .frame(width: textBoxWidth, height: 2)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(hex: "#BCBEC0"))

                Capsule()
                    .frame(width: textBoxWidth, height: 2)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(hex: "#367878"))
                    .offset(x: (beforeCursor ? textBoxWidth : 0) + (afterCursor ? -textBoxWidth : 0))
                    .animation(.easeInOut, value: [beforeCursor, afterCursor])
                    .opacity(isEditing ? 1 : 0)
            }
            .clipped()
        })
        .padding(paddingOfBox)
}
```

And where you use this function (albeit, quite messy and you could clean up your code with a loop, and an array instead of `otp1`, `otp2`, etc.):

```
HStack (spacing: spaceBetweenLines){
    otpText(text: viewModel.otp1, isEditing: viewModel.isEditing, beforeCursor: 0 < viewModel.otpField.count, afterCursor: false)
    otpText(text: viewModel.otp2, isEditing: viewModel.isEditing, beforeCursor: 1 < viewModel.otpField.count, afterCursor: viewModel.otpField.count < 1)
    otpText(text: viewModel.otp3, isEditing: viewModel.isEditing, beforeCursor: 2 < viewModel.otpField.count, afterCursor: viewModel.otpField.count < 2)
    otpText(text: viewModel.otp4, isEditing: viewModel.isEditing, beforeCursor: 3 < viewModel.otpField.count, afterCursor: viewModel.otpField.count < 3)
    otpText(text: viewModel.otp5, isEditing: viewModel.isEditing, beforeCursor: 4 < viewModel.otpField.count, afterCursor: viewModel.otpField.count < 4)
    otpText(text: viewModel.otp6, isEditing: viewModel.isEditing, beforeCursor: false, afterCursor: viewModel.otpField.count < 5)
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

---

To clean up your code, remove all the `otp1`, `otp2`, etc and replace with below:

```
func otp(digit: Int) -> String {
    guard otpField.count >= digit else {
        return ""
    }
    return String(Array(otpField)[digit - 1])
}
```

Then you can simplify the view code:

```
HStack (spacing: spaceBetweenLines){
    ForEach(1 ... 6, id: \.self) { digit in
        otpText(
            text: viewModel.otp(digit: digit),
            isEditing: viewModel.isEditing,
            beforeCursor: digit - 1 < viewModel.otpField.count,
            afterCursor: viewModel.otpField.count < digit - 1
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @George, this is very close but the underline should only turn to green when it is selected. Your implementation turns the first line to green by default. Expected should be there are only gray lines until the text is selected. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: @MyronDulay Fixed! See edit history for changes.

Comment: @MyronDulay Great! Also added bit at end of answer just now to show you how you can simplify your code.

Comment: Hi George, it works now sorry my bad at adding the function. im really new in swift UI

Comment: Hi @George, may I ask what is the use of beforeCursor and afterCursor? for example beforeCursor = true

Comment: @MyronDulay `beforeCursor` is `true` when the `otpText` is _before_ where the current underline should be. `afterCursor` is `true` when the `otpText` is _after_ where the current underline should be. This is so we know which direction to offset the underline by, so it appears from the correct side.

Comment: @George hi how can detect user entered last number to do something?

Comment: @AminRezaew Using the OP's code, use an `onChange(of:perform:)` when `otpField.count == 6`

Answer (score 1):

I add some new updates to @Georges answer, with this code you can give all numbers and when user put the last number try to do something...

```
struct VerifyView: View {

@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

@StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
@State var isFocused = false

@State var code = ""

@State var time = 120

@State var codes: [String] = []
  
let textBoxWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 8
let textBoxHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 6
let spaceBetweenBoxes: CGFloat = 8
let paddingOfBox: CGFloat = 1
var textFieldOriginalWidth: CGFloat {
      (textBoxWidth*6)+(spaceBetweenBoxes*3)+((paddingOfBox*2)*3)
  }
  
  var body: some View {
          
      NavigationView {
          ZStack {
              Color(.yellow).ignoresSafeArea()
              Color(.blue)
              VStack(spacing: 20) {
              
                      ZStack {

                          HStack (spacing: spaceBetweenBoxes) {
                              
                              otpText(text: viewModel.otp1)
                                  .onChange(of: viewModel.otp1) { newValue in
                                      print(newValue)
                                      codes.append(newValue)
                                  }
                              otpText(text: viewModel.otp2)
                                  .onChange(of: viewModel.otp2) { newValue in
                                      print(newValue)
                                      codes.append(newValue)
                                  }
                              otpText(text: viewModel.otp3)
                                  .onChange(of: viewModel.otp3) { newValue in
                                      print(newValue)
                                      codes.append(newValue)
                                  }
                              otpText(text: viewModel.otp4)
                                  .onChange(of: viewModel.otp4) { newValue in
                                      print(newValue)
                                      codes.append(newValue)
                                  }
                              otpText(text: viewModel.otp5)
                                  .onChange(of: viewModel.otp5) { newValue in
                                      print(newValue)
                                      codes.append(newValue)
                                      getCode()
                                      // Here you can do everything like request to your api.
                                      //Now your "code" object have the numbers which user entered.
                                              
                                          }
                          }
                          
                          
                          TextField("", text: $viewModel.otpField)
                          .frame(width: isFocused ? 0 : textFieldOriginalWidth, height: textBoxHeight)
                          .disabled(viewModel.isTextFieldDisabled)
                          .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
                          .foregroundColor(.clear)
                          .accentColor(.clear)
                          .background(Color.clear)
                          .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                      }
                  
                 
          }
          .navigationBarHidden(true)
      }
  }

func getCode() {
    code = codes.joined(separator: "")
    print(code)
}

  private func otpText(text: String) -> some View {
      
      return Text(text)
          .font(.title)
          .frame(width: textBoxWidth, height: textBoxHeight)
          .background(ZStack{
              Rectangle().fill()
                  .foregroundColor(.clear)
              Rectangle()
                  .strokeBorder(Color.accentColor, lineWidth: 2)
      }
          )
          .padding(paddingOfBox)
  }}
```

and the view model which is for you:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var otpField = "" {
    didSet {
        guard otpField.count <= 5,
              otpField.last?.isNumber ?? true else {
            otpField = oldValue
            return
        }
    }
}
var otp1: String {
    guard otpField.count >= 1 else {
        return ""
    }
    return String(Array(otpField)[0])
}
var otp2: String {
    guard otpField.count >= 2 else {
        return ""
    }
    return String(Array(otpField)[1])
}
var otp3: String {
    guard otpField.count >= 3 else {
        return ""
    }
    return String(Array(otpField)[2])
}
var otp4: String {
    guard otpField.count >= 4 else {
        return ""
    }
    return String(Array(otpField)[3])
}

var otp5: String {
    guard otpField.count >= 5 else {
        return ""
    }
    return String(Array(otpField)[4])
}

@Published var borderColor: Color = .accentColor
@Published var isTextFieldDisabled = false
var successCompletionHandler: (()->())?

@Published var showResendText = false }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you aren't properly offsetting the color, therefore it defaults to a color fade. The green underlining is a separate component that shifts based on where the pointer is.