OTP component I can not delete the letters in SwiftUI
All characters are expected to be filled so that I can delete the letters.
However, I want letters to be deleted without all characters being filled. I want them to be deleted one by one backwards by decreasing the index number

Code:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var letters = ["","","","",""]
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            ForEach(letters.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                TextField("", text: $letters[index].limit(1))
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: index)
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .stroke()
                    )
                    .onChange(of: letters[index]) { newValue in
                        if newValue == "" && focusedField == index {
                            if index > 0 {
                                focusedField = index - 1
                            }
                        } else if !newValue.isEmpty && focusedField == index {
                            if index < letters.count - 1 {
                                focusedField = index + 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            focusedField = 0
        }
    }
}


maybe this post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69025986/creating-otp-page-for-swiftui-using-textfield

You cannot detect pressing backspace unless at the very end with this design because you move the focus to the field (which is empty) as soon as the user types anything.
Instead, change the design so that you move the focus to the next field when the user types more than one character. In addition to moving the focus, you should move that extra character to the next field too. This way, when the focus moves, the destination text field will always have one character for the user to delete.
.onChange(of: letters[index]) { newValue in
    guard focusedField == index else { return }
    if newValue == "" && index > 0 {
        // same as your code
        focusedField = index - 1
    } else if newValue.count > 1 { // when there is more than one character in the text field
        let endIndex = index + newValue.count
        
        if endIndex <= letters.endIndex {
            // "spread" the extra characters across the letters array
            // this also handles the case of pasting multiple letters at once
            letters.replaceSubrange(index..<endIndex, with: newValue.map { String($0) })
            // move the focus to the text field into which the last character is inserted
            focusedField = endIndex - 1
        } else { // the inserted characters exceeds the character limit
            // I'm truncated everything to just the first character here
            // you might prefer to do something else
            letters[index] = String(newValue[newValue.startIndex])
        }
    }
}

Note that the text field's binding is just $letters[index]:
TextField("", text: $letters[index])

You should not write .limit(1), whatever that does.

You should change the focus on each button tap from the keyboard. You can use the letters.count to focus on the specific TextField and change it in .onChange
Something like this...
if letters.count {
    focusedField = letters.count + 1
}

Then it will focus on the next field of the last filled field. And use letters
instead of index like this focused($focusedField, equals: letters + 1)
Hope this will help.
Note: Ask me if the concept is not clear to you.
