# How to move to next field programmatically in nested custom form with custom fields in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-tabview

I have list of custom fields in a custom form view. The form view is loaded in the content view, which will inform the form view to move to the next field, when the user taps on "Next" button.

The question is how the form view will make the next custom field focused, when the `moveToNextField()` function called?

This is how my form looks like

[image]

*Here's the code for the custom field*

```
enum InputFieldType {
    case text, number, dropdown
}

struct CustomField: View {
    let tag: Int
    let type: InputFieldType
    let title: String
    var dropdownItems: Array<String> = []
    var placeholder: String = ""
    @State var text: String = ""
    @State var enabled: Bool = true

    @FocusState private var focusField: Bool
    private let dropdownImage = Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
    @State private var showDropdown: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8.0) {
            Text(title)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .frame(alignment: .leading)
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                // The placeholder view
                Text(placeholder).foregroundColor( enabled ? .gray.opacity(0.3) : .gray.opacity(0.5))
                    .opacity(text.isEmpty ? 1 : 0)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                // Text field
                TextField("", text: $text)
                    .disabled(!enabled)
                    .frame(height: 44)
                    .textInputAutocapitalization(.sentences)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                    .keyboardType( type == .number ? .decimalPad : .default)
                    .focused($focusField)

            }.background(Color.red.opacity(0.1))
                .cornerRadius(5)
        }
    }
}
```

*Here's the code for the form view*

```
struct FormView: View {

    func moveToNextField() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack(spacing: 24) {
                    CustomField(tag: 0, type: .text, title: "First name", placeholder: "John", text: "", enabled: false)
                    CustomField(tag: 1, type: .text, title: "Surname", placeholder: "Mike", text: "")
                    CustomField(tag: 2, type: .text, title: "Gender (Optional)", placeholder: "Optional", text: "")
                    CustomField(tag: 3, type: .dropdown, title: "Body type", dropdownItems: ["1", "2", "3"], placeholder: "Skinny", text: "")
                    CustomField(tag: 4, type: .number, title: "Year of birth", placeholder: "2000", text: "")
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }.onTapGesture {

        }
        .background(Color.clear)
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
    }
}
```

*The code in the Content view*

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let formView = FormView()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer(minLength: 30)
            formView
                .padding(.vertical)
            Button("Next") {
                if formView.moveToNextField()  {
                    return
                }
                // validate the form
            }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 44, maxHeight: 44, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.secondary)
                .cornerRadius(5)
                .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            Spacer(minLength: 20)
        }.background(Color.primary)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can one change the FocusState of a SwiftUI app with TextFields in different child views without having View refresh which causes a bounce effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70268416/how-can-one-change-the-focusstate-of-a-swiftui-app-with-textfields-in-different)

Comment: @Yrb Thanks for commenting, wasn't really quite the same question and not the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue, I was using `@State` to track the current focused field, which is getting reset every time the view changes.

So I had to us `@ObservableObject` with `@Published` property.

Here is my final working code.

**Custom field**

```
enum InputFieldType {
    case text, number, dropdown
}

struct CustomField: View {
    let tag: Int
    let type: InputFieldType
    let title: String
    var dropdownItems: Array<String> = []
    var placeholder: String = ""
    @State var text: String = ""
    @State var enabled: Bool = true
    @Binding var focusTag: Int

    @FocusState private var focusField: Bool
    private let dropdownImage = Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
    @State private var showDropdown: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8.0) {
            Text(title)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .frame(alignment: .leading)
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                // The placeholder view
                Text(placeholder).foregroundColor( enabled ? .gray.opacity(0.3) : .gray.opacity(0.5))
                    .opacity(text.isEmpty ? 1 : 0)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                // Text field
                TextField("", text: $text)
                    .disabled(!enabled)
                    .frame(height: 44)
                    .textInputAutocapitalization(.sentences)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                    .keyboardType( type == .number ? .decimalPad : .default)
                    .onChange(of: focusTag, perform: { newValue in
                        focusField = newValue == tag
                    })
                    .focused($focusField)
                    .onChange(of: focusField, perform: { newValue in
                        if type != .dropdown, newValue, focusTag != tag {
                            focusTag = tag
                        }
                    })

            }.background(Color.red.opacity(0.1))
                .cornerRadius(5)
        }
    }
}
```

**Form view**

```
fileprivate class FocusStateObserver: ObservableObject {
    @Published var focusFieldTag: Int = -1
}

struct FormView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var focusStateObserver = FocusStateObserver()

    func moveToNextField() -> Bool {
        if focusStateObserver.focusFieldTag < 4 {
            switch focusStateObserver.focusFieldTag {
            case 0:
                focusStateObserver.focusFieldTag = 1
            case 1:
                focusStateObserver.focusFieldTag = 2
            case 2:
                focusStateObserver.focusFieldTag = 4
            default:
                break
            }

            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack(spacing: 24) {
                    CustomField(tag: 0, type: .text, title: "First name", placeholder: "John", text: "", enabled: false, focusTag: $focusStateObserver.focusFieldTag)
                    CustomField(tag: 1, type: .text, title: "Surname", placeholder: "Mike", text: "", focusTag: $focusStateObserver.focusFieldTag)
                    CustomField(tag: 2, type: .text, title: "Gender (Optional)", placeholder: "Optional", text: "", focusTag: $focusStateObserver.focusFieldTag)
                    CustomField(tag: 3, type: .dropdown, title: "Body type", dropdownItems: ["1", "2", "3"], placeholder: "Skinny", text: "", focusTag: $focusStateObserver.focusFieldTag)
                    CustomField(tag: 4, type: .number, title: "Year of birth", placeholder: "2000", text: "", focusTag: $focusStateObserver.focusFieldTag)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }.onTapGesture {
            endEditing()
        }
        .background(Color.clear)
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
    }
}

extension View {
    func endEditing() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```

**Content view**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let formView = FormView()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer(minLength: 30)
            formView
                .padding(.vertical)
            Button("Next") {
                if formView.moveToNextField()  {
                    return
                }
                endEditing()
            }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 44, maxHeight: 44, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.secondary)
                .cornerRadius(5)
                .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            Spacer(minLength: 20)
        }.background(Color.primary)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a FocusState var for each field. Then turn on the state of the field where you want to move the focus.